# lightning design system lookup component not working

Tags: lightning-design-system

I realize this is a prototype but I can't even make sense of the base example shown here:
http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups#overview&role=regular&status=all

I assume this should work as a typeahead component that filters the results and allows the user to select one. I can't get the example on their pageto filter or do anything and I'm having the same result when copying the sample HTML into my page.

The example displaying the simulated results for the 'ac' search isn't even displayed the correct filtered results. Am I missing something here or is this prototype not actually usable at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation it looks like components like lookup,datepicker, etc. are purely CSS. This means its up to the developer to write the javascript to make it work. Originally, I had thought the javascript must have been part of their core library.

Comment: LDS is a pure CSS framework. There is n javascript like bootstrap. Consider same thing for Modal and Popover as well.

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. Could you please let me know how you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but [Design System React](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/) is open source now and helpful if you want to go off-platform/lightning:container and use React.